# Wordpress not choosing the right image from srcset

Tags: images, responsive

For some reason Wordpress isn't loading the right image from the server and instead is always taking the one with 960px width, no matter if I open the page with a smartphone or the browser.

This is my image elemnt:

```
<img class="header-img responsive-img" 
src="DSC01834-e1487244486122.jpg" 
srcset="DSC01834-e1487244486122-350x58.jpg 350w, 
        DSC01834-e1487244486122-768x128.jpg 768w, 
        DSC01834-e1487244486122-960x160.jpg 960w, 
        DSC01834-e1487244486122-560x93.jpg 560w" 
sizes="(min-width: 48em) 960px, 
       (min-width: 35em) 768px, 
       (min-width: 25em) 560px, 
       350px" 
alt="SONY DSC">
```

Is something wrong with the sizes I specified? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: What do you mean WordPress not choosing the right image? This happens in the client (your browser) - how are you sure that `srcset` is being ignored? Which clients have you tested in?

Comment: I've tested in Chrome by looking up the currentSrc in the Inspector under the Properties tab. Since it didn't work there and it always took the 960px image I have not tested in other browsers yet